# Почему контент на некоторых телефонах не отражается?

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование

Столкнулся только что с проблемой, что на некоторых устройствах не отображается контент. Контент не отображается конкретно тот, который приходит мне от GET запроса, отправляю я его при помощи axios, потом кидаю этот контент в useState и дальше проверяю, есть ли data (наш useSate) если есть - вывожу. Все хорошо работает, но почему-то на некоторых устройствах не хочет. Взял свой андроид на тест, зашел через Гугл - не отображается, зашел через Mi Browser - работает. Какие причины могут быть? Куда смотреть? Я даже не могу глянуть консоль, ибо проблемы на телефонах. Код не кидаю, тк проблема я уверен не в коде.